# I am having problems creating a loop for an array that contains the integers 1-25 and prints 5 numbers per line

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am a greenhorn taking my first Java Programming class and I am having issues with the following: (my code is below)  The output is crazy and I cannot get the output to look like this:

```
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,10
11,12,13,14,15
16,17,18,19,20
21,22,23,24,25
```

Any advice/suggestions would be truly appreciated!

```
//**
public class MidtermExam3
{

public static void main(String[] args){

int[] numbers = new int[25];
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  if (i % 5 == 0 && i > 0) {
     System.out.println();
  }
  System.out.print(numbers[i] + "1,2,3,4,5");
  }
   for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
   if (i % 10 == 0 && i > 0) {
     System.out.println();
  }
  System.out.print(numbers[i] + "6,7,8,9,10");
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
   if (i % 15 == 0 && i > 0) {
     System.out.println();
  }
  System.out.print(numbers[i] + "11,12,13,14,15");
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
   if (i % 20 == 0 && i > 0) {
     System.out.println();
  }
  System.out.print(numbers[i] + "16,17,18,19,20");
  }
   for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (i % 25 == 0 && i > 0) {
     System.out.println();
  }
  System.out.print(numbers[i] + "21,22,23,24,25");
  }


 }

}
```

Comment: Just keep the first for loop without the `+ "1,2,3,4,5"`part, and the output will be what you want (except for the commas, but you should figure that out by yourself).

Answer (score 2):

You have too many loops, and too many print statements.  It looks like you wrote all the code and didn't test along the way.  The best advice for Greenhorns is to test CONSTANTLY.

Start by just trying to get the numbers 1-25 to print, then apply formatting code after that.  Test as often as you can, and when you don't get the expected result you will know which lines were modified since it broke.

Comment: I appreciate the responses, and the best advice yet, Alexander, is from you.  I've been testing this for about 10 hours using jGRASP and NetBeans, lol, and couldn't get a loop to work.

Comment: Considering how complicated the code you posted is, have you tried deleting the whole block of code and simply writing a single FOR loop with 1 println(); in it?  That's the first time you should test, after those 2 lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple issues. First, you don't need an `int[]` at all. Second, you don't print the literal strings you're printing (e.g. "1,2,3,4,5"). Third .. my that's a lot of loops; you only need one.

You have the right idea with using the modulo to print the new line. What you need to change your code to do is:

- loop 1 - 25
- print the number
- check the modulo

  - if it's zero, print a newline
  - if it's not, print a `,`